# Erro na consulta do mysql no php

Tags: php, mysql

Eu faço uma consulta no `DB` `mysql` e funciona normal, depois vou fazer a segunda consulta e me da o seguinte erro:

> **Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs**

Segue o código PHP abaixo:

```
<php>
$open = new OpenDB();
$open->conectarNovamente($_SESSION['usuario'], $_SESSION['senha']);    

$hoje = date('Y-m-d');

$sql = "call proc_rel_controle_diario(NOW(),0,0)";  // ADD 1 dia 
$r = mysql_query($sql);
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($r);
$dia1 = $obj->total_geral;

$sql = "call proc_rel_controle_diario(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY,0,0)";  // ADD 1 dia 
$r = mysql_query($sql);
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($r);
$dia2 = $obj->total_geral;
```

Comment: no mysql workbench faço do mesmo jeito e funciona das duas maneiras, só que no php não.

Comment: O problema é que as funções mysql_* não funcionam corretamente com stored procedures o recomendado é vc trocar elas pelo mysqli ou pdo. [por que não devemos usar as funções mysql_*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: Sempre usei mysql_* em procedure, nunca tive problemas, mesmo assim usei a recomendação mysqli_* é deu outro erro `Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs`

Comment: Nas linhas que tem `mysql($sql)`, deixe assim para exibir o erro: `$r = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` e coloque a mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, utilize o MySQLi e se puder também use orientado a objeto, seu código ficaria dessa forma.

```
$con = new mysqli(@$_SESSION['servidor'], $_SESSION['usuario'], $_SESSION['senha'], "local");

$hoje = date('Y-m-d');

$sql = "call proc_rel_controle_diario(NOW(),0,0);";  // ADD 1 dia 
$r = $con->query($sql);
$obj = $r->fetch_array();
$dia1 = $obj->total_geral;
echo $dia1;

$sql = "call proc_rel_controle_diario(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY,0,0);";  // ADD 1 dia 
$r = $con->query($sql);
$obj = $r->fetch_array();
$dia2 = $obj->total_geral;
echo $dia2;
```

[Mais informações sobre MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0):

resolvi o problema, precisa abri outra conexão para a outra procedure funcionar, só não sei porque disso.

Obrigado perdeu pela dica, vou usar o mysqli_* porque nem sabia sobre a descontinuação do mysql_*.

o codigo ficou assim

```
$open = new OpenDB();
$con = mysqli_connect(@$_SESSION['servidor'],$_SESSION['usuario'],$_SESSION['senha'],"local");

$hoje = date('Y-m-d');

$sql = "call proc_rel_controle_diario(NOW(),0,0);";  // ADD 1 dia 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$obj = mysqli_fetch_object($r);
$dia1 = $obj->total_geral;
echo $dia1;

$con = mysqli_connect(@$_SESSION['servidor'],$_SESSION['usuario'],$_SESSION['senha'],"local");
$sql = "call proc_rel_controle_diario(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY,0,0);";  // ADD 1 dia 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$obj = mysqli_fetch_object($r);
$dia2 = $obj->total_geral;
echo $dia2;
```